# How to remove multiple <br><br/> from content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, replace

I have this content:

```html
<div class="newscontent">
  <p class="article-lead">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in laoreet fermentum, ac turpis quam, libero in
    tincidunt orci at, nec sociosqu, accumsan sed eget pretium libero deserunt
    suscipit.
  </p>

  Lectus lobortis aenean odio posuere tellus non, tincidunt urna nec rhoncus
  wisi, turpis eros duis lorem dui sagittis, convallis arcu vestibulum non ad
  non.<br /><br />
  <br /><br />Lacinia aliquet, adipiscing egestas, quae consectetuer vel, nulla
  mattis aenean quam risus commodo. Egestas ipsum nunc vitae amet. Proin
  molestie, in rhoncus, in pellentesque vitae aliquam quis suscipit lorem, eu
  metus quis adipiscing tempus ante. Donec non morbi parturient. Libero nam
  pretium ipsum adipiscing risus cras.<br /><br />

  <br /><br />Ultrices elit nec mauris, ante consequat, nec sapien mi pharetra.
  Quam proin, non sem tortor, dis odio et. Justo lectus quis, tincidunt praesent
  fermentum eu, quis risus, tempor at eros id nunc eget urna, at sem pulvinar
  ullamcorper accumsan.<br /><br />Etiam maecenas leo eget, aliquet faucibus mi
  lectus erat rhoncus turpis. Velit tristique ante. Morbi et ipsum at dolor
  nunc, tristique sed gravida in eu molestie viverra.
</div>
```

And i want to remove multiple multiple `<br><br/>` to one `<br><br/>` between two paragraphs.

```js
var ta = document.getElementById('b');
ta.innerHTML = ta.replace("<br><br/><br><br/>", "<br><br/>");
```

```html
<div class="newscontent">

  <p class="article-lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in laoreet fermentum, ac turpis quam, libero in tincidunt orci at, nec sociosqu, accumsan sed eget pretium libero deserunt suscipit.</p>

     
     
Lectus lobortis aenean odio posuere tellus non, tincidunt urna nec rhoncus wisi, turpis eros duis lorem dui sagittis, convallis arcu vestibulum non ad non.<br/><br/> <br/><br/>Lacinia aliquet, adipiscing egestas, quae consectetuer vel, nulla mattis aenean quam risus commodo. Egestas ipsum nunc vitae amet. Proin molestie, in rhoncus, in pellentesque vitae aliquam quis suscipit lorem, eu metus quis adipiscing tempus ante. Donec non morbi parturient. Libero nam pretium ipsum adipiscing risus cras.<br/><br/>
 
 <br/><br/>Ultrices elit nec mauris, ante consequat, nec sapien mi pharetra. Quam proin, non sem tortor, dis odio et. Justo lectus quis, tincidunt praesent fermentum eu, quis risus, tempor at eros id nunc eget urna, at sem pulvinar ullamcorper accumsan.<br/><br/>Etiam maecenas leo eget, aliquet faucibus mi lectus erat rhoncus turpis. Velit tristique ante. Morbi et ipsum at dolor nunc, tristique sed gravida in eu molestie viverra. 
     
        </div>
```

Comment: Using jQuery it would be `$('br + br').remove();` (remove any `<br>` adjacent to another `<br>`). http://jsfiddle.net/1nsyqebe/1/

Comment: Or in CSS `.newscontent br + br {display: none;}`

Comment: using regex `.replace(/(<br *\/?>){2,}/g, '<br/>');`

Comment: So who is creating that html? Because to mix <br> and <br /> is not a clean way. Inside your fiddle you are searching vor an id "b", but inside your html I can not find any id with "b".

Comment: You can replace it with an empty string. Use it like;

content.replace(/targetText/g, sourceText);

Comment: $('br + br').remove(); and .newscontent br + br {display: none;} working fine, but i need one <br> pause between two paragraphs. Regex not working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay your problem is you are not taking the element in the right way, and also, you cant make a replace of an HTML element, you have to make replace of a string, so first change replace for an '.innerHTML.replace', and then change your replaces words. Here the correction ;)

```
var ta = document.getElementsByClassName('newscontent')[0];
console.log(ta.innerHTML);
ta.innerHTML = ta.innerHTML.replace(/<br><br>/gi, "<br>");
console.log(ta.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression will sort this right out for you.

To match explicitly a series of 4 `<br />`s (in varying formats), you want a regex like this:

```
/(<br[^\/>]*\/?>\s*){4}/gi
```

This works like so:

- `<br` matches the start of our tag
- `[^>\/]*` matches zero or more characters other than `>` or `/`
- `\/?` optionally matches a `/`
- `>` matches the end of our tag
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.
- `(...){4}` matches exactly 4 instances of whatever's between `(` and `)`

So, used in your code, it'll look something like this:

```
ta.innerHTML = ta.innerHTML.replace(/(<br[^\/>]*\/?>\s*){4}/gi, '<br /><br />');
```

Naturally, if you wanted to, instead, replace any 2 `<br />`s with a single one, I'm sure you can figure out what to change!